# How to error read in expect with out executing other commands?

Tags: tcl, telnet, expect, cisco

I am having an issue. I have a simple expect script that i call in a php script to login to a cisco terminal server to clear vty lines after a lab time is over. The logic is simple that if a user is present then it only occupies line vty 0.

The problem occurs if a user is not present... the cisco router just displays an error stating %connection to clear or something and expect run the rest of the script which is not necessary because i am managing a lab of 10 routers and loading configuration files which takes a lot of time.

Please tell me how to read the error from log and end script if i get that message.

---

```sh
#! /usr/bin/expect -f

spawn telnet 192.168.2.1
set user [lindex $argv 0]
set pass [lindex $argv 1]
expect "Username:"
send "$user\r"
expect "Password:"
send "$pass\r"
expect "*>"
send "enable\r"
expect "*#"
send "clear line vty 0\r"
send "\r"
expect "*#"
send "copy tftp://192.168.2.3 running-config\r"
send "config\r"
send "\r"
expect "*#\r\n"
```

Comment: % Not allowed to clear current line  
This is the output i get once it sees that line 0 is occupied by himself. I can deny to access this line but still i don't want this script to reload config once it knows that no user is there. plus one other thing that how to determine which string it expects dynamically and send a command depending on that...like sometime when it telnet into a router it gets ">" and some other time it gets "#" which makes a mess. so i want to check which string is it and then issue the appropriate command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error handling code you are asking about is here...

```sh
send "clear line vty 0\r"
expect {
    "confirm]" { send "\r" }
    "% Not allowed" { send "quit\r"; exit }
}
expect "#"
```

This looks for either `[confirm]` or `% Not allowed to clear current line` and makes an appropriate go / no-go decision.

I made a few modifications to your script so I could run it against machines in my lab.  I'm not sure how you disabled the router from asking for an enable password, but that may be something to add to your script.

If you wanted to make the script more robust, you could issue a `show user` before clearing lines, and only clear lines that your script isn't on.  I will leave that as an exercise for you to experiment with.

---

```sh
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn telnet 172.16.1.5
set user [lindex $argv 0]
set pass [lindex $argv 1]

expect "Username: "
send "$user\r"
expect "assword: "
send "$pass\r"
expect ">"
send "enable\r"
expect "assword: "
send "$pass\r"
expect "#"
send "clear line vty 0\r"
expect {
    "confirm]" { send "\r" }
    "% Not allowed" { send "quit\r"; exit }
}
expect "#"
send "copy tftp://192.168.2.3 running-config\r"
expect "Source filename *]? "
send "config\r"
expect "Destination filename *]? "
send "running\r"
expect "#"
exit
```

Comment: awesome :) and one more problem...which i am trying and its 3:36 in the morning but couldn't find an answer :(. The copy tftp command works fine on my terminal server and loads the config file. I have another config file named **r1** but i can't get it work on a router connected to the terminal server. I don't what is the possible reason as it seem strange that a file works on terminal server but not on a router!!

Comment: It's hard to say what the problem is... does the **r1** config work when you paste it in your router?  If not, it's in the contents of the config file itself.

Comment: It's the file i copied from the router itself so i don't think there is some problem with the file. I am just testing so i configured the router and copied it's config file so that when i mess around in the lab after the lab time it can just reload old config. I don't know what is the problem